# Ethereum full node size

Tags: ether

I would like to start a Geth full node, and I have to see how much SSD to buy. How can I have an appropriate estimate on the full size of an ethereal full node?
Thanks

Comment: last second the size of Ethereum`geth`  full node was 535196460 KBytes

Comment: archival node is 6 TB